# Intermittent response when querying Cluster IP in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, coredns, kube-dns

We're experiencing an issue when we try and query one service in our Kubernetes cluster from another pod. Occasionally, the request goes through but 99% of the time it fails. This happens also when we try and directly hit our kube-dns service:

```
/ # nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local.
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I can see the the above request come through in the core-dns logs so I think its not a DNS resolution issue:

```
[INFO] 10.2.56.172:53295 - 403 "A IN kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. udp 54 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 106 0.000158582s
```

Similar failures happen when trying to hit any service in our cluster. Here you can see it work once and then fail right after

```
/ # dig http://172.20.234.169:80

; <<>> DiG 9.11.6-P1 <<>> http://172.20.234.169:80
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 2504
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 16db935520e8e061 (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;http://172.20.234.169:80.  IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           30  IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2021072201 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 52 msec
;; SERVER: 172.20.0.10#53(172.20.0.10)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 22 20:12:33 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 140

/ # dig http://172.20.234.169:80

; <<>> DiG 9.11.6-P1 <<>> http://172.20.234.169:80
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Our setup:

1. Cloud Provider: AWS running EKS
2. 4 nodes running on k8s 1.20; core-dns 1.8
3. Setup is completely private running in its own VPC with 4 subnets

Other info

```
⇒  kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
aws-node-8n9r6                                1/1     Running   0          2d2h
aws-node-gpd5p                                1/1     Running   0          2d2h
aws-node-mdl98                                1/1     Running   0          2d3h
aws-node-tff7q                                1/1     Running   0          2d3h
coredns-55cd7f87dc-csnnk                      1/1     Running   0          4h3m
coredns-55cd7f87dc-d4bl2                      1/1     Running   0          4h3m
coredns-55cd7f87dc-hkj85                      1/1     Running   0          4h3m
coredns-55cd7f87dc-ms4kx                      1/1     Running   0          4h3m
kube-proxy-77zdf                              1/1     Running   0          130m
kube-proxy-fv8tc                              1/1     Running   0          129m
kube-proxy-nklhv                              1/1     Running   0          129m
kube-proxy-wvvmf                              1/1     Running   0          129m
seldon-spartakus-volunteer-5b57b95596-gsk2d   1/1     Running   0          2d3h
```

```
⇒  kubectl get svc kube-dns -n kube-system
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kube-dns   ClusterIP   172.20.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   22d
```

```
/ # cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 172.20.0.10
search lpa.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local us-west-2.compute.internal
options ndots:5
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Any luck solving this?

Comment: @KeithP Yes we had to allow inbound Custom UDP  traffic to ports 30000 - 65535 at our NACL as well as on port 53. I believe that's what fixed it for us.